# Overlay autocomplete fragment on map fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I'm trying to overlay a autocomplete fragment over a mapfragment. 
Problem is my autocomplete is transparent, it does not get the white background i set. Any tips on this?

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MapsActivity"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom" />

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/place_autocomplete_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceAutocompleteFragment" />
</FrameLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    map:uiZoomControls="true"
    map:uiZoomGestures="true"
    map:mapType="normal"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MapsActivity">
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.greenfeetsurvival.greenfeetaviator.MapsActivity">
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/card_view"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">
            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/place_autocomplete_fragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"    
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceAutocompleteFragment" />
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    </fragment>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is the layout I used in my app.  The PlaceAutocompleteFragment looks exactly like the Google tool.  It sits at the top left corner on top of the map with a 5dp margin.

Comment: When I tried to used this android shows error. Cannot find "PlaceAutocompleteFragment"

Comment: Without seeing your code it's hard to tell what's going on.  Make sure you have all the latest SDK's and Google API's loaded in your programming environment.  If you're using Android Studio try checking for updates using the "SDK Manager".  Make sure you include "com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceAutocompleteFragment"